# Invalid Operation with Decimal

Tags: python

I'm using beautiful soup to extract information from a website and to get the price of an item.
I used the code below to create a variable names prices to store the information. Then I created a loop to iterate through all of the items and now I'm trying to compare it to another variable named price_thres to determine if its less than or equal to the amount. Running this code prints a few of the correct values but it also prints

```
    price_in_dec = Decimal(i.text)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

```
prices = soup.find_all("span", itemprop="price")

for i in prices:
    price_in_dec = Decimal(i.text)
    if price_in_dec <= price_thres:
        print(price_in_dec)
```

Comment: May we please know which website are you trying to scrape? or add part of the HTML? I believe your issue is with one of the items.

Comment: The URL is https://www.ammobuy.com/ammo/9mm I'm pulling the price data from the site and it's displaying properly, but it throws that error at the end after printing 6 of the prices below the price_thres which is Decimal(40.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have commas (`,`) in some of your prices.

Try this:

```
import locale

# Set to US locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'USA')

prices = soup.find_all("span", itemprop="price")

for i in prices:
    price_in_dec = Decimal(locale.atof(i.text))
    if price_in_dec <= price_thres:
        print(price_in_dec)
```

By using the correct locale, you can parse the prices according to the way you write them in the US.

Another option would be to simply remove commas using `i.text.replace(",", "")`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, some of the prices print out a lot bigger than I need them to so is there an easy way I can stop them after the cents position? An example of what it prints now is "26.969999999999998863131622783839702606201171875"

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I used the i.text.replace and it fixed my issue. Thanks so much that helped a ton and I understand why it was throwing an error now!

Comment: Hi @zach_hutz, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)